# Erro na instalação do gulp

Tags: laravel, bower, gulp

Estou instalando o gulp no meu Windows 7 pelo comando `gulp` . Mas está me dando o seguinte erro:

```
[11:21:03] Error in plugin 'gulp-bower'
Message:
    Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/thomaspark/
bootswatch.git", exit code of #128
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error
```

OBS.: Já criei a variável ambiente do sistema apontando para a instalação do node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá! Já tive esse problema uma vez, pode ser o firewall.
Resolvi com o seguinte comando:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Ele substitui o protocolo do clone.
Espero que ajude!

Comment: bah funcionou aqui 100%, valeu